# Problem using tolerance in numeric question with 'moodle' package in latex

Tags: moodle

When adding tolerance to a numeric question, an error appears as shown in the example bellow:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{moodle}
\begin{document}
\begin{quiz}{Prueba}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{numerical}[points=5,tolerance={0.0001}]{Pregunta01}

 $\pi$ es igual a

\item 3.14159
\end{numerical}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{cloze}{Pregunta02}
$\pi$ es igual a
\begin{numerical}[points=2, ,tolerance={0.0001}]
\item 3.14159
\end{numerical}

$e$ es igual a
\begin{numerical}[points=2, ,tolerance={0.0001}]
\item 2.71828
\end{numerical}
\end{cloze}
\end{quiz}
\end{document}
```

I have as result:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

**Update**: Matthieu (@mgk) found that the problem is (as often happens) the `babel` package playing with category codes of characters to implement its shorthands. My suggestion is, at least for the Spanish language, to always load the `babel` package without shorthands and use Unicode to input the special chars directly.

Effectively, it seems that the distributed `moodle.sty` (which is at version 0.9) has a problem there, but (if you do not activate the shorthands for Spanish language) it's fixed in 1.0.

I am running 1.0 from [the source](https://framagit.org/mattgk/moodle), and running a slight variation of your code with `lualatex` (hint: if you are not writing in English, use `lualatex` and input your files directly in utf8, without any shorthand from babel --- most of them will not work), I have a correct behavior:

```latex
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[english, spanish, es-noshorthands, shorthands=off]{babel}
\usepackage{moodle}
\begin{document}
\begin{quiz}{Prueba}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{numerical}[points=5,tolerance={0.0001}]{Pregunta01}

 $\pi$ es igual a

\item 3.14159
\end{numerical}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{cloze}{Pregunta02}
$\pi$ es igual a
\begin{numerical}[points=2, ,tolerance={0.0001}]
\item 3.14159
\end{numerical}

$e$ es igual a
\begin{numerical}[points=2, ,tolerance={0.0001}]
\item 2.71828
\end{numerical}
\end{cloze}
\end{quiz}
\end{document}
```

The PDF is:

[image: PDF output]

And in Moodle it works:

[image: Moodle report for the quiz]

It seem form the main source that a new release is in the making, which is good news.

Comment: @mgk --- do you agree?

Comment: yes. If the fix I suggested works, I'm not sure that the best thing is to advise spanish-writing users of `babel` to disable shorthands, similarly to what we do for german, french and turkish-writing users.

Comment: Thank you all very much! This was very helpful! Did not notice that babel could make this problem.

Answer (score 1):

The OP ran into a bug that [was fixed](https://framagit.org/mattgk/moodle/-/issues/107) some time ago. The fix is present in the recently released [in version 1.0](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/moodle) of the `moodle` package.

@Rmano uncovered another problem: this one was unknown to me. From my understanding, the `spanish` option of the package `babel` seems to change the catcode of the symbols `<` and  `>`. These symbols are used by `moodle` to write XML code...

The following code placed in the preamble should make `moodle` more robust to the changes introduced by `babel`:

```latex
{\catcode`\<=12\gdef\otherlessthan{<}
\catcode`\>=12\gdef\othergreaterthan{>}}
\makeatletter
\html@action@def\HTMLtag#1{%
    \xa\g@addto@macro\xa\htmlize@output\xa{\otherlessthan#1\othergreaterthan}%
  }%
\makeatother
```

This fix will be published soon in the development version.

Comment: Thank you very much!